# replace m2 file on ububtu server 18.04

Tags: linux, maven

I install the Apache Maven on Ubuntu server with Apt with `sudo apt install maven`

I am new to Linux but as I am understanding this installation produces an  `m2 repository`.

what is want is the following:

first how to find and inspect this `m2`?
second how to replace this m2 with an `m2 repository`  that I have download to my desktop?

Comment: First the `apt install maven` will not create the directory `.m2/repository` only if you execute `mvn ...` The location of the local cache (aka repository) is `$HOME/.m2/repository` (users home directory) usually not root

Comment: @khmarbaise i execute the $HOME/.m2/repository and i get  -bash: /home/aggelos/.m2/repository: Is a directory

Comment: That must be created beforehand cause during the `apt install maven` my assumption would be it that it's not created. But it could be?... I'm not sure about the ubuntu RPM's. What do you mean by `.. have download to my desktop?`? Do you mean on an other machine? Other user?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes I have a windows pc where via putty i control the ubuntu server. on this windows pc I have an .m2 repository and I want to transfer it and replace the m2 folder on ubuntu server. Now I can see this folder using  the ls-al

Comment: Not a good idea. Let Maven download the things needed into your local home directory on the windows machine... no sharing etc. will not solve any problem.

Comment: @khmarbaise. if i still want to do this can you help me with the command please? is start I think with pscp -r ?

Comment: My question keeps: What kind of problem are you trying to solve? Or what advantage do you think you have to use a local cache from your server instead of having it on your local machine? Apart from that: When/Why/ you would like to sync/update etc. it?

Comment: @loutsi You may have noticed that you have a much better chance of getting help when you explain _why_ you want to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, maven's local repository is located in the user's home directory.  In fact it's actually named ".m2" directory, instead of just "m2".  It is a hidden directory.  If you are not in your home directory, issue "cd ~" first.  Then issue "ls -al" to see the presence of .m2 directory.

If for any reason, you do not see that "m2" directory after issuing above command, it simply means that you did not built or run any project that requires maven to get triggered and create that .m2 folder.

ps: Replacing the existing .m2 folder with the one you have on your desktop may not be a good idea.  Instead, simply run the project (that you think requires the needed dependencies). This will build the .m2 directory afresh along with everything that app needs.

Comment: yes @gopale thanks, I see the .m2 folder with "ls-al". But as my instructions suggested I must first replace this folder with the folder that I have in my desktop. Can you help e with that? Thanks

Comment: if you still want to do that, then make a back up of the existing folder using command "mv ~/.m2 ~/.m2_backup".  Then copy the existing .m2 folder from your Desktop to your home directory using "cp -ar ~/Desktop/.m2 ~/"